# Initializing a class not connected to other classes -- Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, initialization

I'm trying to initialize a singular class in my RoR application. This Batch class is not connected to any other class, it is used solely for the Rails API I have set up.

This is the Batch class:

```
class Batch < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :access_bucket

  def access_bucket
    s3 = AWS::S3.new
    bucket = s3.buckets['curateanalytics']
    bucket.objects.each do |obj|
      if obj =~ /swipe batches/i && obj =~ /jpg/i
        self.sort_objs(obj.key)
      end
    end
  end

  def sort_objs(url)
    swipe = url.split("swipe batches/").last
    batch_id = url.split("swipe batches/")[1]
    folder = swipe.split("/")[0] 
    self.initialize(batch_id, folder, url)
  end

  def initialize()
    batch = Batch.new
    batch.batch_id = batch_id
    batch.folder = folder
    batch.url = url
    batch.save!
  end
end
```

I honestly had no idea where to go so I created a `before_create :create_batch` method in my User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :like
  has_one :outfit
  has_one :wardrobe
  before_create :create_batch
  after_create :create_wardrobe, :create_outfit, :create_like
  serialize :preferences

  def self.from_omniauth(auth_hash)
    where(auth_hash.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.curate_user_id = "curate"+rand(9).to_s+rand(9).to_s+rand(9).to_s+
        rand(9).to_s+rand(9).to_s
      user.provider = auth_hash.provider
      user.uid = auth_hash.uid
      user.name = auth_hash.info.name
      user.email = auth_hash.info.email
      user.image = auth_hash.info.image
      user.oauth_token = auth_hash.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth_hash.credentials.expires_at)
      user.preferences = { height: nil, weight: nil, age: nil, waist_size: nil, inseam: nil, preferred_pants_fit: nil, shirt_size: nil, preferred_shirt_fit: nil, shoe_size: nil}
      user.save!
    end
  end

  private
  def create_batch
   @batch = Batch.new
   @batch.save!
  end
end
```

When I ran the server I received the message that the stack was too deep. Am I wrong in thinking that this path should access the Batch class and the Batch.access_bucket method which would then lead to the initialize method?

Comment: Stack level has to do with this `Batch.new` calls `Batch.new` inside it's initialize method so this becomes infinitely cyclical. Beyond that there are many more issues with how batch is created including the fact that overriding the initialize method of an `ActiveRecord::Base` object seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: Does Batch have (or need) a table in the database? It doesn't have to inherit from ActiveRecord::Base; it can just be a plain old Ruby class to wrap the accessing of AWS data.

Comment: I do plan on it being a plain old Ruby class that accesses only the AWS. I assume I can delete the `ActiveRecord::Base` and then access the data pulled from the AWS in the Batch API controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete initialize method in the Batch class.

When you call new on a Class, it instantiates an object and call initialize on it. So when you call Batch.new in create_batch method of your User class, the initialize method of you Batch class is called. The problem is that Batch#initialize method calls Batch.new inside it, so another Batch#initialize is invoked, which calls Batch.new inside it, which again calls another Batch#initialize, and infinite cycle of Bathc.new and Batch#initialize follows.